# How to specify CryptoComply algorithm provider in new Spring SAML2?

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0

Our identity provider uses keys and certificates in the `BCFKS` format.  To use that format in key tool we specify the CryptoComply algorithm (not service) provider like so:

```
keytool.exe -list -keystore key.store -storepass some.password ^
-storetype BCFKS ^
-providername CCJ ^
-providerClass com.safelogic.cryptocomply.jcajce.provider.CryptoComplyFipsProvider ^
-providerpath ccj-3.0.1.jar
```

How do we do the same thing with the new Spring `SAML2` configuration?  Are there some properties that can be set to accomplish that?

Below is a sample "`application.yml`":

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          idprovider:
            signing:
              credentials: &rp-metadata
              - private-key-location: classpath:credentials/rp-private.key
                certificate-location: classpath:credentials/rp-certificate.crt
            identityprovider:
              metadata-uri: file:///drive$\metadata_folder\saml2-metadata.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the service provider does not need to use the same file format for its key store as the identity provider.  The IDP can use a BCFKS key store, and the SP can use a JKS key store, and they 2 can still communicate.  The format of the key stores does not affect the certificates themselves sent across the wire.  In our case, it was not necessary for the SP to use a BCFKS key store.  To specify key store types in Spring "`application.properties`" for example, these can be used:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
saml.keystore.type=${server.ssl.key-store-type}
```